# Can't create object inside migrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm extending `django.contrib.auth.User` model with my model:

```
class Farmer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="farmer")
    mob_phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

I want to create some of these Farmer instances during migrations, so i have a python-migration job, which goes after all other migrations :

```
def create_farmers(apps, schema_editor):
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    Farmer = apps.get_model("farmer", "Farmer")
    User = get_user_model()

    u = User.objects.using(db_alias).create(username="kek" ,password="lol")
    farmer = Farmer.objects.using(db_alias).create(id=1, user=u, mob_phone="1")
```

I run this job in `operations` section just like all other migrations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(create_farmers, revert_create_farmers),
]
```

But Django is laughing in my face with

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: kek>": "Farmer.user" must be a "User" instance.
```

This is knocking me off, because `u` is definitely as `User` instance!

Comment: it may be because you are assigning an id. Try without including the id.   `Farmer.objects.using(db_alias).create(user=u, mob_phone="1")`

Comment: You also will want to make use of `User.objects.create_user()` instead of just `.create()`

Comment: This didn't help, Ben.
I found the problem, though. I will post solution later.
Django is so....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made my migration work - not sure if it's legitimate way.
Anyway, here's my wisdom.

When you use `apps.get_model("<app>", "<Model>")` in migration operations, django seems to import not an exact `<Model>`, but something like a . I made this conclusion, when reading the django sources for  class inside migrations. Inside that sources i found an assert, which is comparing my forignKey User type with type `_fake.User`. Of course my real User of type 
`django.contrib.auth.models.User` is not the same as `_fake.User`, and django through that partially incorrect message:
`ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: kek>": "Farmer.user" must be a "User" instance.`

The solution was to import a real Farmer model from the app - not to user the `apps.get_model("<app>", "<Model>")` method